# Unable to save Enum values into entity field from DropDownList - EF Code First MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a DropDownList that contains the correct items and values when the view is rendered but the selected value is not being saved within the designated entity field Garage. Currently the value being saved and returned is 0 (None) in both create or edit post methods.  I'm sure this is something simple but I can't figure it out... Thanks in advance!

The Model Class:

```
public enum GarageType { None = 0, One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3, Four = 4 }

public int Garage { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public GarageType GarageEnumValue
{
    get { return (GarageType)Garage; }
    set{ Garage = (int)value; }
}
```

The Control Create and Edit methods both look like this:

```
var statuses = from Property.GarageType s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Property.GarageType))
                       select new { ID = (int)s, Name = s.ToString() };
ViewBag.GarageId = new SelectList(statuses, "ID", "Name", statuses.FirstOrDefault().ID);
```

Last the View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("GarageId", String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following overload of [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883.aspx) method

```
@Html.DropDownList("GarageEnumValue", (SelectList)ViewBag.GarageId, String.Empty)
```

If you have a strongly type model use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GarageEnumValue, (SelectList)ViewBag.GarageId, String.Empty)
```

The first argument in both cases should be the **property** that you are going to bind the list.

Comment: That corrected my problem with creating and now the correct value is being saved in the table field Garage. When I try and edit that same record the DropDownList does not populate with the same selected value from when I created the entry. The value is set back to zero. I added this line to both create and edit methods @Html.DropDownList("GarageEnumValue", (SelectList)ViewBag.GarageId, String.Empty)

Comment: I found a solution to my last question was to not use the first string parameter GrageEnumValue but instead go directly to the property Garage:  @Html.DropDownList("Garage", (SelectList)ViewBag.GarageId, String.Empty) Thanks for the help!~

Comment: See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Wow-That's excellent content on how to code a DropDownList in MVC Thanks!